# Obtaining different results when using `facet_wrap()` in `ggplot`

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am using this code to download data from `yahoo finance` and plot some stocks against the S&P500 after normalising the `adjusted` prices.

The following code returns;

```
Ra <- c("NFLX") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")

Rb <- "SPY" %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")

stock_returns_daily <- Ra
benchmark_returns_daily <- Rb  

RaRb <- left_join(stock_returns_daily, benchmark_returns_daily, by = c("date" = "date"))
normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]


RaRb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = normalise_series(adjusted.x)-1), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(y = normalise_series(adjusted.y)-1), color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Daily Stock Prices",
       x = "", y = "Adjusted Prices", color = "") +
 #facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_color_tq()
```

This figure (Which is the normalised Netflix stock price against the S&P500) :

[image]

This looks intuitive and correct to me, both start at the origin `0`, however when I try to add in other stocks `AMZN`, `FB`, `GOOG` and `NFLX` and also uncommenting the `facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +` I do not get the same plot any more. I use the same code and it gives me two different outputs.

```
Ra <- c("AMZN","FB","GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")


Rb <- "SPY" %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")

stock_returns_daily <- Ra
benchmark_returns_daily <- Rb  

RaRb <- left_join(stock_returns_daily, benchmark_returns_daily, by = c("date" = "date"))
normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]


RaRb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = normalise_series(adjusted.x) -1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = normalise_series(adjusted.y) -1), linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(title = "Daily Stock Prices",
       x = "", y = "Adjusted Prices", color = "") +
  facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_color_tq()
```

Giving me the following;

[image]

Now `NFLX` is negative and gives me a different plot.

Comment: I would guess this has to do with `normalize series`, which might be normalizing the combination of all four stocks together rather than separately. The scale of the Y-axis also gives a hint to this. Try entering the data set as the data normalized within each stock rather than using the `normalize.series` function in the `gpplot` call. Doing so normalizes the entire data set together, rather than normalizing by the faceting variables. You should do that normalizing outside `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question thanks to a comment from [@Noah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6348551/noah) in this question and to some guidance from [@MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) in a question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332447/applying-a-function-within-mutate-from-dplyr/51332589#51332589).

The following code seems to get what I want.

```
Ra <- c("AMZN","FB","GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")


Rb <- "SPY" %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")

stock_returns_daily <- Ra
benchmark_returns_daily <- Rb  

RaRb <- left_join(stock_returns_daily, benchmark_returns_daily, by = c("date" = "date"))
normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]

RaRb <- RaRb %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  select(symbol, date, adjusted.x, adjusted.y) %>%
  mutate(adj.x = normalise_series(adjusted.x)) %>%
  mutate(adj.y = normalise_series(adjusted.y))


RaRb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = adj.x -1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = adj.y -1), linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(title = "Daily Stock Prices",
       x = "", y = "Adjusted Prices", color = "") +
  facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_color_tq()
```

Which is this output:

[image]

The `NFLX` is now identical to the first plot in the original message.