# Applying a function within `mutate()` from `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a custom function within the `dplyr` package.

Data & function

```
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)

Ra <- c("AMZN","FB","GOOG", "NFLX") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")


Rb <- "SPY" %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from = "2013-01-01",
         to = "2016-12-31")

stock_returns_daily <- Ra
benchmark_returns_daily <- Rb  

RaRb <- left_join(stock_returns_daily, benchmark_returns_daily, by = c("date" = "date"))
normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]
```

(Note: This is a follow up question regarding a previous post I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330838/obtaining-different-results-when-using-facet-wrap-in-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment89637771_51330838) which is not directly related to this question).

I am trying to apply the `normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]` part of the above code to a `dplyr` piece. What I have so far is;

```
x <- RaRb %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  select(symbol, adjusted.x) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(adj.x = normalise_series(adjusted.x))
```

And I am not completely sure why this is not working. I know I am missing something but do not know what/why. The column I create, just creates a vector one 1`s

I am trying to apply the function (a normalisation function on stock prices) to each group in the `dataframe` and not the whole column. (whereas, as pointed out by [@Noah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6348551/noah) I was applying the normalisation function across all stocks.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Comment: My apologies, I am using a package called `tidyquant`

Comment: Huh, well that certainly did something different... I will go away and apply it to my problem and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rowwise()` verb makes it so each command is performed separately on each row. This is not what you want because you want to normalize over all the values in the group. Not one row. Just take that part out.

```
x <- RaRb %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  select(symbol, adjusted.x) %>%
  mutate(adj.x = normalise_series(adjusted.x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been able to answer my previous question now also! Here is the final code which worked for me. `RaRb <- RaRb %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  select(symbol, date, adjusted.x, adjusted.y) %>%
  mutate(adj.x = normalise_series(adjusted.x)) %>%
  mutate(adj.y = normalise_series(adjusted.y))`

Comment: Thanks again, here is my solution to the other problem I had regrading plotting the normalised returns. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330838/obtaining-different-results-when-using-facet-wrap-in-ggplot/51332702#51332702)